# Loading helper files into FactoryBot files gives `cannot load such file`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am trying to use a helper method in my `FactoryBot` file, but when I call `require rails_helper` I get a `require: cannot load such file -- support/geocoder_helper (LoadError)`.

`spec/factories/members.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

require 'support/geocoder_helper'

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :member do
    association :user, roles: ['Member']
    cohort

    after(:build) do |member, _evaluator|
      if member.user
        add_geocoder_stub(member.user.full_address_string)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`spec/support/geocoder_helper.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

DEFAULT_GEOCODER_STUB_RESULTS = [
  {
    'coordinates' => [11, -13],
    'address' => '123 Main St, Los Angeles, CA, USA',
    'state' => 'Los Angeles',
    'state_code' => 'CA',
    'country' => 'United States',
    'country_code' => 'US'
  }.freeze
].freeze

def add_geocoder_stub(address, results = DEFAULT_GEOCODER_STUB_RESULTS)
  address = User.new(address).full_address_string if address.is_a?(Hash)

  Geocoder::Lookup::Test.add_stub(address, results)
end
```

`spec/support/factory_bot.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end
```

`spec/rails_helper.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

...
```

Result:

```
in `require': cannot load such file -- support/geocoder_helper (LoadError)
```

This result is the same for all different helpers and all factories.
I am able to use helpers in non FactoryBot files using the same `require` patterns.

Versions:
rails (5.2.4.6)

rspec (3.9.0)

factory_bot (4.10.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spec` folder is not in your `load_path`. You can either:

- use absolute path `require Rails.root.join('support/geocoder_helper')`
- use relative require `require_relative '../support/geocoder_helper'`
- add `spec` folder to your load (in spec_helper.rb): `$LOAD_PATH << Rails.root.join('spec')`
- require all your support files in spec_helper, which is pretty standard procedure

Other issues: **do not define methods on `main` object**. It is quite a terrible practice that I keep fixing in most of the specs, causing a lot of really odd behaviours and subtle bugs. Once the geocoder_helper file is loaded, `add_geocoder_stub` method is defined on `Object` class making it available in every single object globally (that is including `nil`, `true`, all symbols etc). This is just, well, yucky - not to mention it might cause unexpected behaviour changes as suddenly `respond_to?` will return true and you just don't know what other libraries might be using this.

Instead, wrap your method in modules:

```
module GeocoderHelper
  module_function

  DEFAULT_GEOCODER_STUB_RESULTS = [
    ...
  ].freeze

  def add_geocoder_stub(address, results = DEFAULT_GEOCODER_STUB_RESULTS)
    address = User.new(address).full_address_string if address.is_a?(Hash)

    Geocoder::Lookup::Test.add_stub(address, results)
  end
end
```

and use it only when required:

```
after(:build) do |member, _evaluator|
  if member.user
    GeocoderHelper.add_geocoder_stub(member.user.full_address_string)
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |rspec|
  rspec.include GecoderHelper
end
```

### EDIT

As it seems you are able to require support files from your spec files then it means that you already do option 3 from the above, but FactoryBot is required before this happens (most likely on bundler setup). One option to fix it would be to modify your Gemfile from:

```
gem 'factory_bot_rails'
```

to

```
gem 'factory_bot_rails', require: false
```

which will prevent factories to be loaded on Bundler setup. You then need to load them manually with `require 'factory_bot_rails'` **after** you added spec to your load path - most likely in your spec_helper (but also check your rails_helper, config/environments/test.rb and initializers).

Comment: If it is an issue with 'spec' not being in my load path, why can I use `require 'support/geocoder_helper'` in other files inside of the 'spec' directory and it works? It only breaks with FactoryBot

Comment: @TheCaptan - Answer edited